# JSF2 lazy loading - how to get next page programmatically?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, lazy-loading

I've implemented DataTable - Lazy Loading sample. Similar to [this one](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf), but I load data from database - it's not important though.

So I have:

```
public class LazyCarDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Car> { 

    ...
}
```

and

```
public class TableBean {  

    private LazyDataModel<Car> lazyModel;  

    ...
}
```

Somewhere, very deep in the procject I need to know what the current page of this Car list looks like. So I do:

```
List<T> currentCarList = (List<T>)getTestTableBean().getLazyModel().getWrappedData();
```

and I have. Last loaded cars (currently visiable in the browser). But, I also need to see, what WILL BE next and previos page. I mean before user clicks "Next page" there will be a warning massage "attention! there will be Ferrari on the next page!" :D

So, finally my question: 
**How to get next and previos page when using lazy loading?**

Comment: If you see in your link (showcase) in `LazyCarDataModel` there's a `public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters)`. This method is called each time users performs a change in the paginator. With first and pageSize you can load the data you need. Last page or previous is apparently not kept, but you can do it by yourself in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just keep track of it yourself in the `LazyDataModel#load()` method.

```
private List<Car> prev;
private List<Car> next;

@Override
public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map filters) {
    this.setRowCount(service.count());
    this.prev = service.list(first - pageSize, pageSize);
    this.next = service.list(first + pageSize, pageSize);
    return service.list(first, pageSize);
}    

public List<Car> getPrev() {
    return prev;
}

public List<Car> getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

Wherever you need it, just do

```
List<Car> prev = tableBean.getLazyCarDataModel().getPrev();
// ...
```